# SVN commit date and time different from the ubuntu server time

Tags: svn, ubuntu

I set up SVN in ubuntu server for my team here problem is, the commit times are not in sync with the server time, at any instant if anyone commits, in the svn log it records different time, how do i sync server time and SVN time? thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

I think you should configure your ntp clients:

Either right now:

```
/usr/sbin/ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

Or if you want to do it automatically:

Install ntp:

```
sudo apt-get install ntp
```

Configure ntp:

```
vi /etc/ntp.conf
```

Add some ntp server (at least one) from [ntp pool](http://www.pool.ntp.org). For example:

server 0.europe.pool.ntp.org

Restart ntp service:

```
/etc/init.d/ntpd restart
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so SVN does not take time from the server?? my server now shows the correct time but svn still off by a couple of hours...i restarted apache but doesn't seem to work...